# How to seed a separate table with foreign keys in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I have three tables with genres, movies and their relationship. I want to create a seed for the relationship table but don't really know how to do it exactly so the genre_id and movie_id would have the same number id. Here's the migration for the genres:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('genres', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
        });
    }
```

Movies:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('movies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('status')->nullable()->default(0);
            $table->string('image_path')->default('images/default.png');
        });
    }
```

Relationship:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('genre_movie', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignId('genre_id')->constrained();
            $table->foreignId('movie_id')->constrained();
        });
    }
```

Here's the movie model:

```
class Movie extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'status', 'image_path'];

    public function genres()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Menu::class, 'genre_movie');
    }
}
```

Here's the genre model:

```
class Genre extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function movies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Movie::class, 'genre_movie');
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no other way than to firstly seed data for genre and movie table. Then you add their id as foreign key in necessary table you needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seed your `genres` and `movies` tables initially, then you can use those to seed your `genre_movie` table. So for example:

```
// Seed 10 genres
Genere::factory(10)->create();

// Seed 50 movies
Movie::factory(50)->create();

// Seed some relationships
foreach (Genre::all() as $genre) {
    $movies = Movie::inRandomOrder()->take(random_int(1, Movie::count())->get();
    $genre->movies()->attach($movies);
}
```

*Update 1*

> is there a way to control how many records its gonna create for the `genre_movie` table?

Yup.

```
$movies = Movie::inRandomOrder()->take(10)->get();
```

Altering the parameter value provided to `take(x)` will define how many records are created in the `genre_movie` table for each `Genre`. In the above example it will create `10` records per `Genre`. That could be set to two with `take(2)` etc.

Alternatively you could always just grab the `first()` `Movie` record if you just want a single `Movie` per `Genre` in your `genre_movie` table.

```
$movies = Movie::inRandomOrder()->first();
```

Comment: this seems to work but for some reason foreach loop creates like 200-300 records in the database although I only have 10 genres, I tried to make some changes but nothing seems to work yet

Comment: @ИльяДерий Creates 200-300 records in which table, the pivot table? If so that would be expected as the `foreach` is taking a random number of movies from the `movies` table and assigning them to a `Genre`. Using the above your `genres` table should have 10 records and your `movies` table 50 records. The number of records in `genre_movie` will be random as previously explained.

Comment: is there a way to control how many records its gonna create for the genre_movie table?

Comment: @ИльяДерий I have updated my question to describe how you might achieve a limited number of records.